# Switch from sequential to parallel execution in a Python script

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to write a Python script that wraps many Fortran subroutines. I'd like to do this in order to define parameters in one place (the .py) and then run the Fortran functions by passing these parameters. Within *main.py*, functions are compiled and executed as

```
os.system("f2py -c routine1.f90 -m r1")
import r1
r1.func1(para1, para2, ..., paraN)
```

I use the iPython environment, so I just

```
> $run main.py
```

and everything works fine, especially if some warning arises, within iPython I like I can readily check what went wrong.

Now, one routine I need is parallelized in MPI. I found I can compile as

```
> f2py --f90exec=mpif90 -m rpara -c routinepara.f90
```

but the execution command is

```
> mpiexec -n 8 python main.py
```

So, I need to run main.py in parallel since the beginning and without using iPython. Is there any workaround to achieve what I have in mind (that is, run *main.py* and then at a certain point within the script, after calling a number of sequential Fortran routine, call the parallel routine)?

Comment: one option is to start one process (e.g. `singleton` mode) and then `MPI_Comm_spawn()` when you need to "go parallel".

Comment: i din't know `MPI_Comm_spawn()` but from a first look on the web it seems a Fortran command. Instead, I would like Python to execute an already parallel Fortran routine. I'm not sure my point is clear

Comment: there is a `mpi4py` binding for `MPI_Comm_spawn()`. It is then up to you to call the (parallel) subroutine in the parent process and the spawned children.